# How to use generics in an abstract class that is extending a React Component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am creating an abstract class that extends a React Component and I want to be able to set some default Props but also let the component extending the abstract class provide their own props.

```
interface Props {                                                                       
  someProps: boolean                                                                    
}                                                                                       

abstract class AbstractPureForm<P, S> extends React.Component<Props & P, S> {
  ...
}
```

How it would be used:

```
class Other extends AbstractPureForm<{ newProps: string}, {}> { 
  ...
}
```

Right now this setup is giving me the errors:

```
does not exist on type '(Props & P)["..."]'
```

Comment: Where (what line) do you get this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Reference: [How to write an abstract class for a component (with extendable state & props)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48061654/5951226)*

## Writing the abstract class

Rather than `Props & P` (there's no way to specify this as a generic type parameter, as far as I know), your abstract class should take a generic value for its props, of type `P extends Props`:

```
export interface Props {
    someProps: boolean;
}

export abstract class AbstractPureForm<P extends Props, S> extends React.Component<P, S>{
    // ...
}
```

## Writing the concrete subclass

### Providing props by extending the `Props` interface

Your concrete subclass, `Other`, should take in props that explicitly extend the abstract class's `Props` interface via `OtherProps extends Props`:

```
interface OtherProps extends Props {
    newProps: string;
}

class Other extends AbstractPureForm<OtherProps, {}> { 
    // ...
}
```

### Providing props by intersecting with the `Props` interface

You could, equally make use of intersection types as you had originally been doing, by creating a type `OtherConcreteProps & Props` (the intersection of the props for both your concrete subclass and the abstract class):

```
interface OtherConcreteProps {
    newProps: string;
}

export type OtherProps = OtherConcreteProps & Props;

class Other extends AbstractPureForm<OtherProps, {}> { 
    // ...
}
```