# How to write an abstract class for a component (with extendable state & props)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to write an abstract ReactJS class, then extend it. I'll thus need to extend its `props` and `state` (as far as I understand; I'm new to React).

Based on [Nitzan's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39124219/5951226) showing how to extend `props` from a base class, I made an abstract class `Animal`:

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface AnimalProps {
    isHibernatory: boolean;
}

export interface AnimalState {
    shouldHibernate: boolean;
}

// TS2322: Type '{ shouldHibernate: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<S>'.
export abstract class Animal<P extends AnimalProps, S extends AnimalState>
    extends React.Component<P, S> {

    constructor(props: P) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            shouldHibernate: props.isHibernatory
        };
    }
}
```

... And also made a class `Cat` that extends it:

```
import * as React from "react";
import {AnimalProps, AnimalState, Animal} from "./Animal";

export interface CatProps extends AnimalProps {
    isHairless: boolean;
}

export interface CatState extends AnimalState {
    shouldSeekWarmth: boolean;
}

export class Cat extends Animal<CatProps, CatState> {

    constructor(props: P) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            willHibernate: props.isHibernatory,
            shouldSeekWarmth: props.isHairless
        };
    }
}
```

However, as commented, the TypeScript compiler throws the error `TS2322: Type '{ shouldHibernate: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<S>'`. I believe this is because it can't guarantee that `S` will be readonly once it has extended `AnimalState`. How else could I write this? Or am I missing a bigger picture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to cast the anonymous object to `Readonly<S>` and the error went away.

`this.state = { shouldHibernate: props.isHibernatory } as Readonly<S>;`

Comment: why transfer a prop value to the state ? This is an anti-pattern: https://codeburst.io/how-to-not-react-common-anti-patterns-and-gotchas-in-react-40141fe0dcd

Answer (score 10):

React prefers composition over inheritance, may be this is a viable approach in some plain JS patterns but this is not the case.

As you are new to React, take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

"At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven’t found any use cases where we would recommend creating component inheritance hierarchies."

Comment: Hi @Mose, what about the fact that all the components in all React applications _extend_ (inherit) `Component` rather than having a component as a field/property? What if you want a base `Component` whose `componentDidMount` is the same for all the components in your application?